# Passing string with HTML to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am creating a simple modal where I pass a string and that gets displayed as the content of the modal.

In a nutshell, I have this script:

```
   $("[id^='mod_']").click( function() {

      var line1    = $(this).attr("data-modaltext1");

       $('#modalid').show();
       $('#modalmessage').text(line1);
```

The above works as expected. But if my string I pass and picked up by data-modaltext1 is

```
"<p>Hello</p><p>World</p>"
```

It prints is as seen without the html tags working. I don't get two paragraphs. Just one string that looks exactly like

```
 "<p>Hello</p><p>World</p>"
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Change `.text` to `.html`.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `html` method instead so it can be treated as raw html code and not just text:

```
$('#modalmessage').html(line1);
```

Comment: Awesome. Thanks !